# Use PPS for UART and PGC/PGD on PIC32

Tags: pic, uart

I'm using a [PIC32MM0064GPM028](https://www.mouser.se/datasheet/2/268/60001387c-1113833.pdf), all pins are currently used. I would like to use UART2 briefly for sending debug output to a terminal. Datasheet tells me that UART2 and UART3 can be used with PPS (UART1 cannot).

Furthermore, I'm using PGC/PGD1 located on RA0/RA1. These two pins are the only ones not having pull up-resistors or diodes or similiar, because the datasheet tells me having these components on PGC/PGD it will interfere with the programming.

**My question is:** can I map UART2 to RA0/RA1 without the UART-module interfering with the programming of the chip (using Pickit 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as nothing else is hanging on the lines then it will be fine.

When the chip unlocks for programming, all of the PPS selections are unselected. What it will interfere with is if you want to debug using the Pickit3.